# Android Get Time Update

Tags: android, timer

I want to call a specific patch of code regularly after 60 seconds to get the updated data in the application. I am wondering where i should put the code in the Main Android activity. Any help will be appreciated
thanks

Comment: Create a Thread and call AsyncTask in it every minute

Comment: Thanks, can you share the sample of thread code and where should i place that code in the android activity?

Comment: Check this link http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2007/11/stitch-in-time.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use **`Timer`** Class of Java's `util` package. It will allow you to execute a specific code again & again on a regular interval. Have a look at the [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UsejavautilTimertoscheduleatasktoexecuteonce5secondshavepassed.htm) which executes on every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.os.Handler;

public class ExecuteEveryMinuteExample {
    private static final int DELAY_IN_MILLIS = 60000;

    private final Handler handler;
    private final Runnable task;

    public ExecuteEveryMinuteExample(Handler handler, Runnable runnable) {
        this.handler = handler;
        this.task = new Task(runnable);
    }

    public void start() {
        handler.postDelayed(task, DELAY_IN_MILLIS);
    }

    public void stop() {
       handler.removeCallbacks(task);
    }

    private class Task implements Runnable {
        private Runnable task;

        private Task(Runnable runnable) {
            this.task = runnable;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            task.run();
            start();
        }
    }
}
```

This "timer" is associated with Activity lifecycle, remember to stop it in `Activity#onDestroy` or better in `Activity#onPause`. Also checkout [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html), [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) and [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) they may suit your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

use services and broadcast receivers in android.

```
// Restart service every 30 seconds
  private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 1000 * 30;

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MyStartServiceReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Start 30 seconds after boot completed
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
    //
    // Fetch every 30 seconds
    // InexactRepeating allows Android to optimize the energy consumption
    service.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pending);
```

refer this site for more information.

> http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: In my opinion using service to update time on view is overkill.